# Accessing variables by name / type in provider

Tags: flutter

Looking at the docs for [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-) it says:

> The easiest way to read a value is by using the static method
>   Provider.of(BuildContext context). This method will look up in
>   widget tree starting from the widget associated to the BuildContext
>   passed and it will return the nearest variable of type T found (or
>   throw if nothing if found).

So, basically, you access a variable / value by its type, and not its name. Does this mean that each provider can only have a single variable of each type? What if I have two variables of type String? Do I need to wrap those in a custom type and then access them via that type and then the variable name?

Comment: I think you are right, you will need to have a custom type to be able to pass two String (for example),

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this too. So far I've sort of gotten around it by creating a map and returning it in the getter. Also a list would work. I hope to find a better way but this is what I've got so far.

```
class Thing with ChangeNotifier {

  final _things = FullThing().things;

  Map get allThings {
    _things.shuffle();

    Map<String, dynamic> allThings = {
      "h0": _things.sublist(0, 7),
      "h1": _things.sublist(8, 15),
      "h2": _things.sublist(16, 23),
      "h3": _things.sublist(24, 31),
      "h4": _things.sublist(32, 41),
    };

    return allThings;
  }
}
```